# pip packages create executables n OSX but not in Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu

Well, what happens:

When I install, for example, Fabric with:

`pip3 install fabric`

Into OXS, after that I can just type `fab deploy...` but, into Ubuntu, I can't, It asks to run `sudo apt install fabric`

how to setup the PATH?

Comment: PATH should still be modified by apt install. Is it not?

Comment: Where is `pip` installing bin/scripts? On some distros, the default place it installs isn't on your default `$PATH`, so you need to add it. (Or, of course, you can run `python3 -m fab` instead of `fab`, or just make a bash alias to that, etc.)

Comment: What does your *PATH* look like?

Comment: does running `pip3 install fabric` print out something about running `sudo apt install fabric` ? What is the exact output of the commands `pip3 --version` and `pip3 install fabric` ?

Comment: @abarnert, it works when use `python3 -m fab`, thank you!